# Cannot find name for "en_UK" locale code - error in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

So I'm setting up a sylius project using docker and am getting an error when I first tried to load the page. The docker set up on sylius website didn't seem to work so I made my own docker files and can successfully start the docker containers. The error is below:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Cannot find name for "en_UK" locale code").
```

During the installation, sylius asks whether you want en_US or something different so I typed en_UK, presuming that was the notation required. Upon setup completion, I tried to load root page and I get the error message above. However, strangely, on the symfony toolbar on the error page it says US web store.

If anyone could help at all it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible ways:

- go to `localhost/admin`, enter your login/password which you entered at the install moment, open Channels section, and there add change default locale/add new to locale list;
- modify a `<project-root>/config/services.yaml` and change `locale` value to another;
- in the worst case try to run `php bin/console sylius:install` command and reinstall database with a `en_US` at the beginning, then edit Admin section to `en_UK`

Answer (score -1):

`en_UK` means "English (Ukraine)". No wonder it was missing. What you wanted was probably `en_GB`.

Comment: Actually in Sylius it's all about "locales" and you set its code via the admin, so it can be `en_UK` or `en` or even `xx_YY` or `poo`. So your answer is invalid.

Comment: It is "all about locales" indeed, but I don't think you can realistically expect to get a name for a nonexistent locale (whichs is what the error message quoted above is about). I just checked the list of locales available in Sylius, and English (Ukraine) is not in that list (even though there is more than a dozen other "English (foo)" locales available).

Comment: The "Locale" in Sylius are not tied to the locale code in any way. Your answer is simply not valid.